# Is it possible to add a Java Editing area to an Eclipse RCP Part?

Tags: java, editor, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a java editing area to my Eclipse RCP application where the user can create some java code. I have found a good tutorial [here](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/06/opening-editor-without-ifile.html) where I can **open** a java editor without a file so the user can implement some code, but instead of **opening** the java editor I would like it to be **embedded** on my `Part`.

Much like you would attach a `Text` area to the `Part` using `Text textArea = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER)` is it possible to do the same with an instance of an editor? There doesn't seem to be any API to set the parent of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't really easy to be solved. JDT is really complicated and cannot be so easy ported to a ViewPart. There are many Parts, that are dependent with the IEditorPart. There is a similar question on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789892/java-source-code-editor-as-an-eclipse-view).

UPDATE:
I just saw in PlanetEclipse, that [Tom Schindl](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/02/20/from-styledtextviewer-to-a-styledtexteditor-with-javafx8/) is playing with the creation of a FX java editor. You might give it a try and integrate it in your View. It seems to be [possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm) to integrate Java FX components in SWT. Please give a feedback, if that's possible ;)

Comment: Not the best news! :p Instead of extending the eclipse editor do you know of any editors out there with java highlighting capabilities that could be added to a ViewPart?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a solution... However I would use the jdt editor and change the workflow. To show the Java Code in a view you can use: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JavaSourcecodeViewer.htm Maybe you can extend this example to an editor. Another solution would be to use the code from http://www.jedit.org or another open source solution.

Comment: With regards to your update, I've managed to implement a little of what I need from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JavaSourcecodeViewer.htm by simply setting the parent of the text area to my Part and enabling editing in the text area. It provides basic syntax highlighting which is all I need for now. Later down the line when I have time I may look at the FX Java Editor to add some more robust and IDE like functionality :)

Comment: I was looking for that too. I have used the highlighting only to show some code in a wizard, but forgot where the example was from... Nice you found it ;)